# Postgres extract value from jsonb array

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I have a jsonb field with an array like this one below:

```
[  
   {  
      "type":"discount",
      "title":"Discount 10%"
   },
   {        
      "file":"zx5rP8EoacyfhqGndcSOnP8VYtkr9Ya8Nvf7oYL98YDsM1CLMYIurYvfVUU4AGkzBsovwssT0bq.pdf",
      "type":"menu",
      "title":"Some menu title etc"
   }
]
```

I want to get the **file** attribute in case there is a **type=menu** in the array.

What I managed to do is to know if there is one, but how can I eventually extract the file value?

```
case when offers @> '[{"type":"menu"}]' then true else false end
```

I don't want to do something like this below because the array may not contain a discount type.

```
offers->1->'file'
```

Comment: try `json_array_elements` for this?..

Comment: @VaoTsun no luck there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `jsob_array_elements()` and `->>` operator (see [JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html).)

```
with a_table(json_col) as (
values (
'[  
   {  
      "type":"discount",
      "title":"Discount 10%"
   },
   {        
      "file":"zx5rP8EoacyfhqGndcSOnP8VYtkr9Ya8Nvf7oYL98YDsM1CLMYIurYvfVUU4AGkzBsovwssT0bq.pdf",
      "type":"menu",
      "title":"Some menu title etc"
   }
]'::jsonb)
)

select value->>'file' as filename
from a_table,
lateral jsonb_array_elements(json_col)
where value->>'type' = 'menu'

                                    filename                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 zx5rP8EoacyfhqGndcSOnP8VYtkr9Ya8Nvf7oYL98YDsM1CLMYIurYvfVUU4AGkzBsovwssT0bq.pdf
(1 row)
```

Comment: why do you use lateral instead of plain jsonb_array_elements ?

Comment: Functions that return set of rows should be called in the `FROM` clause and lateral join is a natural way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Eg:

```
t=# with a as (with v as (select '[
   {
      "type":"discount",
      "title":"Discount 10%"
   },
   {
      "file":"zx5rP8EoacyfhqGndcSOnP8VYtkr9Ya8Nvf7oYL98YDsM1CLMYIurYvfVUU4AGkzBsovwssT0bq.pdf",
      "type":"menu",
      "title":"Some menu title etc"
   }
]'::jsonb j)
select jsonb_array_elements(j) r from v) select r->>'file' from a where r->>'type' = 'menu';
                                    ?column?
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 zx5rP8EoacyfhqGndcSOnP8VYtkr9Ya8Nvf7oYL98YDsM1CLMYIurYvfVUU4AGkzBsovwssT0bq.pdf
(1 row)
```